# Show the image when button is clicked even after app restarts completely

Tags: android, image

I have a button and an image. When the user clicks the button the image is shown but when the user re-opens the app after it forcefully closes the image is not displayed. But I want to make sure when the button is clicked it should be shown forever no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can store your image state in preferences or some place.
When you start app again,you can judge the value to show/hide your image.